# Unable to import github library to gradle

Tags: android, github, android-library, toast, android-toast

For the very first time, I have been using Fancy Toast library.
https://github.com/Shashank02051997/FancyToast-Android#prerequisites

Then I decided to edit the color and logo the Fancy Toast, after that I did a sync again in my Gradle and did error. Then I hard deleted Fancy Toast Library from Project-External Library- and delete it.

But now I'm unable to import Fancy Toast with gradle anymore, can anyone fix this?

[My App Build Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2O6d.png)

[My project Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFNkC.png)

and now i got this problem
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]

Comment: sure i sync the project gradle and app gradle

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: I have no error now, but i still cant use Fancy Toast for more..

Comment: How do you mean you can't use? Like it doesn't show in autocomplete?

Comment: Fancy toast doenst apear in external libraries, and i cant import fancy toast in my java class